# RangeSlider to show multiple output

Tags: javascript, jquery, rangeslider

I manage to get one output but I want to show multiple outputs as the user slides. How can I achieve this?

Each output having a different value of say 1x, 1.2x, 1.5x, 1.3x and 1.75x

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jadckr71/)**

```js
$('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({polyfill: false});
$('#range').on("input", function() {
$('.output1').val("$"+this.value);
}).trigger("change");
```

```css
output {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rangeslider.js.org/assets/rangeslider.js/dist/rangeslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rangeslider.js.org/assets/rangeslider.js/dist/rangeslider.min.js"></script>
<input type="range"  name="range" id="range" value="100" step="25" min="1" max="1100">
    <br />
    <output class="output1">100</output>
    <output class="output2">120</output>
    <output class="output3">150</output>
    <output class="output4">130</output>
    <output class="output5">175</output>
```

Comment: From where you'll get those values `1x, 1.2x, 1.5x, 1.3x and 1.75x`?? If you want to generate them, then which rules you want to apply?

Comment: Not sure where the multipliers are coming from, but here is a little help for you, handling everything you need to procede for your work: https://jsfiddle.net/jadckr71/3/

Comment: you will get only the value, you should code yourself the other values with the percentiles you need.

Comment: From the default `value` which is 100 in this case.

Comment: @ElaineByene sounds better in this way: https://jsfiddle.net/jadckr71/6/

Comment: @ElaineByene the initial value shows the speed ? or there is no relation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply update all `output` values on change of `range`:

```
$('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({polyfill: false});
$('#range').on("input", function() {
$('.output1').val("$"+parseFloat(this.value*1).toFixed(2));
$('.output2').val("$"+parseFloat(this.value*1.2).toFixed(2));
$('.output3').val("$"+parseFloat(this.value*1.3).toFixed(2));
$('.output4').val("$"+parseFloat(this.value*1.5).toFixed(2));
$('.output5').val("$"+parseFloat(this.value*1.75).toFixed(2));
}).trigger("change");
```

**code snippet:**

```js
$('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({polyfill: false});
$('#range').on("input", function() {
$('.output1').val("$"+parseFloat(this.value*1).toFixed(2));
$('.output2').val("$"+parseFloat(this.value*1.2).toFixed(2));
$('.output3').val("$"+parseFloat(this.value*1.3).toFixed(2));
$('.output4').val("$"+parseFloat(this.value*1.5).toFixed(2));
$('.output5').val("$"+parseFloat(this.value*1.75).toFixed(2));
}).trigger("change");
```

```css
output {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rangeslider.js.org/assets/rangeslider.js/dist/rangeslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rangeslider.js.org/assets/rangeslider.js/dist/rangeslider.min.js"></script>
<input type="range"  name="range" id="range" value="100" step="25" min="1" max="1100">
    <br />
    <output class="output1">100</output>
    <output class="output2">120</output>
    <output class="output3">150</output>
    <output class="output4">130</output>
    <output class="output5">175</output>
```

Comment: Awesome! How do I limit 2 digits after the dot? Instead of `$901.1999999999999`, I would like `$901.20` or just `$901.19`

Comment: parseFloat(yourString).toFixed(2)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({polyfill: false});

var _multipliers = [
    1,2,3,4,5
].map(function(i){
    return (+$('.output'+i).val() / 100);
});

$('#range').on("input", function() {
  var _value = +this.value;
  [1,2,3,4,5].forEach(function(i){
    $('.output'+i).val("$"+ ((1 + _multipliers[i-1]) * _value).toFixed(2));
  });

}).trigger("change");
```

For that case specifically, you can pre-calculate the multipliers by initially acquiring the values out of a map.
In a nutshell, using `.map`, you get all the initial values and divide them by 100, so you will get the multiplier out of them (100 -> 1, 120 -> 1.2.. and so on).

After that, you repeat the same process to acquire the value, by accessing `_multipliers[i-1]`, since indexes are 0-based.

This solution is versatile as long as all "outputs" keep the same notation and format.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jadckr71/6/

Note: the unary operator `+` before many "$" is to cast the variable to a number, so that there is no risk it will be  a string and will, somehow, be concatenated.

Comment: Thanks. I marked the other answer as correct as I found that to be easier to understand. Thank you so much though :)